# Не правильная замена переменной в setInterval

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas

Пишу псевдо-еквалайзер на канвасе. 
Ссылка на [codepen.io](http://codepen.io/Tyuk/pen/RpyyeR).

```
<canvas id="equalizer"></canvas>
```

---

```
(function ($) {
var methods = {
   init: function (options) {
      var p = {
         bar_width: 18,
         bar_heigth: 11,
         row_spacing: 15,
         col_spasing: 23,
         row:7,         //кол-во столбцов
         col:6,         //кол-во колонок
         speed:100,     //скорость подсветки кубиков
         freq:100,      //частота сигнала
         on:true            //включено по умолчанию (true,false)
      };
      if (options) {
         $.extend(p, options); 
      }
      var canvas = $(this)[0],
          ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'),
          stepOld = [],
          stepNew = [];

      ctx.canvas.width  = window.innerWidth;
      ctx.canvas.height = 250;
      ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6)";

      var randomNumber = function (m,n){
         m = parseInt(m);
         n = parseInt(n);
         return Math.floor( Math.random() * (n - m + 1) ) + m;
      },
          drawCanvas = function(){
             var countDrawRows = Math.floor(p.freq/p.speed),
                 drawCount = countDrawRows,
                 exchange = Math.floor(p.row/(countDrawRows>0?countDrawRows:0)),
                 drawRow = function(){
                    //console.log('draw '+(countDrawRows-drawCount));
                    ctx.beginPath();
                    for (var col = 0; col < p.col; col++) {
                       var blocks = exchange*(stepOld[col]-stepNew[col]),
                           rowsNeed = Math.floor(stepOld[col]+(blocks*drawCount)); 
                       for (var row = 0; row < rowsNeed; row++) {
                          ctx.rect(col * p.col_spasing, row * p.row_spacing, p.bar_width, p.bar_heigth);
                       }
                    }
                    ctx.closePath();
                    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
                    ctx.fill();
                    drawCount--;
                    if(drawCount>0){
                       setTimeout(drawRow, p.speed);
                    }else{
                       stepOld = stepNew;
                    }
                 }
             drawRow();
          },
          eqInterval = function(){
             for (var col = 0; col < p.col; col++) {
                stepNew[col] = randomNumber(0,p.row);
             }
             drawCanvas();
          }
      if(p.on){
         for (var col = 0; col < p.col; col++) {
            stepOld[col] = randomNumber(0,p.row);
         }
         drawCanvas();

         eqIntervalId = setInterval(eqInterval,p.freq+10)
         $(this).data({
            'eqIntId':eqIntervalId,
            'eqInt':eqInterval,
            'freq':p.freq,
            'on':p.on
         })
      }else{
         $(this).data({
            'eqIntId':eqIntervalId,
            'eqInt':eqInterval,
            'freq':p.freq,
            'on':p.on
         })
      }

   },
   start: function () {
      if(!$(this).data('on')){
         $(this).data('eqInt')();
         var eqIntervalId = setInterval($(this).data('eqInt'),$(this).data('freq'));
         $(this).data({
            'eqIntId':eqIntervalId,
            'on':true
         })
        }
     },
   stop: function () {
      if($(this).data('on')){
         clearInterval($(this).data('eqIntId'));
         $(this).data({
            'on':false
         })
         var canvas = $(this)[0],
             ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
         ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
      }
   }
};
$.fn.liEqualizer = function (method) {
    if (methods[method]) {
        return methods[method].apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
    } else if (typeof method === 'object' || !method) {
        return methods.init.apply(this, arguments);
    } else {
        $.error('Метод ' + method + ' в jQuery.liEqualizer не существует');
    }
};

})(jQuery);

$('#equalizer').liEqualizer({
    row:13,       //кол-во столбцов
    col: Math.round(window.innerWidth/22),       //кол-во колонок
    speed: 300,    //скорость подсветки кубиков
    freq: 600,    //частота сигнала
    on: true      //включено по умолчанию (true,false)
});
```

Не могу разобраться в какой момент присваивается переменная stepOld = stepNew.

Сейчас в начале отрисовки эквалайзера, старые значения(stepOld) затираются новыми(stepNew). Из-за этого не получается получить разрезы между старым положением и новым.

Как делать замену новых значений в нужный момент?

Comment: непонятно какое поведение есть сейчас и что надо изменить. значение stepOld, меняется в функции _drawRow_, когда все отрисовано, для примера в вопросе это 1 итерация

Comment: В том то и дело что stepOld меняется раньше запланированного. 
В сам эквалайзер обновляется переменной freq, а столбцы переменной speed.

Comment: кроме тебя никто не знает когда изменение _запланировано_. В коде есть еще места где меняется эта переменная. Без понимания того, чем текущее поведение отличается от того, что ты хочешь, вряд ли можно угадать что нужно поправить.

Comment: freq/speed - Количество обновлений самого слайдера.

Проблема в чем: Если вывести в консоли stepOld функции eqInterval(), перед получением stepNew и после, но до отрисовки drawCanvas(), то данные сразу заменяются. Еще до окончания отрисовки. Проблема в setInterval как я понимаю, но не могу найти.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вроде проблема заключалась в том, что обе переменные лежат в одной видимости переменных и в момент получения stepOld, я получал обновленную stepNew.

Вопрос решил переносом stepOld присвоения stepNew, через переменную var stepEx.

P.S. На codepen.io уже все поправлено и изменено.